# Forward error correction in .NET

Tags: c#, forwarderrorcorrection

Are there any libraries (paid or free, though free is obviously better) that provide forward error correction for .NET applications? I've tried looking through the source code of some of the open source C / C++ libraries, but quite frankly, the math is confusing and my inability to read other peoples' C code with any reasonable level of clarity is a major road block.

Comment: Little hope for a google hit when you don't spell it "forward".

Comment: for people like me who wonder what "forward error correction" is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction

Comment: Do you want to understand code or to uderstand how to use this code in your project? In the second case C/C++ library is good enough. In first case better look for any documents and other papers describing how it works.

Comment: @Bart, No offense, but if either were "good enough" for me, I wouldn't be asking the question here, now would I? I've reviewed several papers on the matter and the source code from several projects, and no matter what, I keep getting lost. If I could find an implementation in a language I'm well versed in, it might help me understand it better.

Comment: What type of data are you wanting to do forward error correction on, and what type of communication channel is it transmitted over?  Error checking then requesting retransmissions (ARQ) is sometimes a better choice.

Comment: When you say .NET applications you could use VB.NET which has built in Error Correction.

Comment: I'm consistently amazed at the number of people who attempt to invalidate, rather than answer, questions here. I want to toy around with building a distributed file system in .NET, and I'd like to implement some FEC algorithm for it (basically a distributed RAID parity), but I'm afraid I don't know much about it other than very high level conceptual stuff. This has nothing to do with error checking or error correction, or anything of that sort.

Comment: @Chris - I believe the problem is that your original question was a little vague. The comments about your intent were to try and clarify the situation. Trying to write code using an existing FEC toolkit is an entirely different requirement than trying to implement your own, and will thus result in different answers.

Comment: FEC tends to be mostly used for data transmission, not storage. Do you have more information on how you're planning to use this library?

Answer (score 3):

If you have free C++ libraries why don't you try to build CLI wrapper around them?

Answer (score 1):

[Forward Error Correction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_error_correction) is for instance used in media streaming.

A quick [google search on "forward error correction"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22forward+error+correction%22+c%23) does not reveal much, but you could go another way:

Compile the C/C++ implementation (for instance from the list on [Christian Schuler's Forward Error Correction (FEC) Page](http://home.arcor.de/christianschuler/fec_sw.html)) of your choice into a DLL, then use P/Invoke to call functions in that DLL.

Another option that might fit you is to use the [.NET interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd874027(v=VS.85).aspx) to the [Windows Media Services 9 series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd873819(v=VS.85).aspx).
It contains the [IWMSPublishingPoint interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd893150(v=VS.85).aspx) that has a [EnableFEC property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd874240(VS.85).aspx).

--jeroen

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [PAR2](http://www.par2.net/par2spec.php) format specification? PAR2 files provide raid-like parity for downloaded files (mostly popular on usenet binary groups). Although PAR2 is probably the wrong granularity for you, you should be able to change that once you know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I found a free library on github (made by antiduh):

https://github.com/antiduh/ErrorCorrection

As it said:

> A library to implement Reed-Solomon encoding. Reed Solomon is a method of encoding data with extra error correction information built in, so that errors in received data can be corrected without having to retransmit the data; this technique is also known as Forward Error Correction (FEC).